# Can you predict what the metabolites of pipradrol would be? Are they similar to those of methylphenidate?

Tags: metabolism, pharmacology

As these drugs are structurally very similar, I am curious about how the body would handle them. Ritalinic acid is a major metabolite of methylphenidate, but that's about all I know.

Thanks

---

Methylphenidate: 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methylphenidate#/media/File:Methylphenidate-2D-skeletal.svg

Pipradrol:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pipradrol#/media/File:Pipradrol.svg

Ritalinic acid: 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ritalinic_acid#/media/File:Ritalinic_acid-2D-skeletal.svg